# typedef with same name in different classes Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, syntax, enums, typedef

I have this typedef:

```
//MyClass_1.h

typedef enum
{
   edit,
   copy,
   paste
} textAction;
```

and when I want this typedef in MyClass_2.h:

```
//MyClass_2.h

typedef enum
{
   edit,
   copy,
   paste
} textAction;
```

I have error: Typedef redefinition with types ('enum textAction' vs 'enum textAction'). In MyClass_2.h I didn't use #import MyClass_2!!! Why I have this mistake?

Comment: both has same value so that you can use the one which already created.

Comment: Why do you have to define that in both files? Can't you just do it in Constants.h and `#import` it in both places?

Comment: So typedef enum { edit, copy, paste } textAction; is global operation?

Comment: Define the enumeration only once, then import the class where you defined the enumeration in order to use it.

Comment: Ok. But why this error has been place? MyClass_1 and MyClass_2 is different classes without #import's. So typedef enum { edit, copy, paste } textAction; it's not private ?

Answer (score 2):

use the same enum in both classes.
put the enum in a .h file and include it in both other .h
this way the exact same enum is prepared for the compiler.

the way you use it, it is 2 different (but same looking) enums for the linker/compiler and stuff.